# Veracrypt and GPG Suite - can I uninstall GPG Suite and keep a working Veracrypt?

Tags: macos, veracrypt

I've been getting nags from GPG Suite/gpgtools to upgrade for a few days now on my mac.

Now, I am not totally clear on how I got it in the first place, but I believe that I had to install it in order to install Veracrypt.

I don't use it for anything else and I don't much like having another update daemon running itself to check for updates.  Can I get rid of it and keep Veracrypt working?  Or is there no link whatsoever?

edit:  I did find the **Automatically check for updates** under **System Preferences/GPG Suite**, so I guess I could turn that off.  But really, not a fan of having lots of apps installed on my machine, so I would just as soon ditch GPG Suite.

BTW, in case it's not clear; "you don't have a clue, GPG suite has nothing to do with Veracrypt and I run Veracrypt perfectly fine without GPG Suite" is a perfectly valid answer.  So is "you don't have a choice, Veracrypt needs GPG Suite".

Answer (score 0):

Veracrypt and I run Veracrypt perfectly fine without GPG Suite" is the correct answer. Certainly Veracrypt does not require GPG to work, and GPG has an entirely different purpose to Veracrypt.

PGP (GPG is an implementation of PGP) can be used to verify that the Veracrypt software you got is a legitimate version - ie does not have any backdoors. It is not required by Veracrypt once you have ascertained the Veracrypt package is authentic.  Its possible the tutorial you used made use of GPG to verify the fingerprint.